# Telegram Bot run commands from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm quite new to working with telegram bots, but I managed well so far with some basic bot. Now I want to improve a bit things and let my site "feed" the bot.

This is the scenario

I have a Google spreadsheet that make some calculation and then sends a message to the bot with the classic URL. Something like this...

```
var optionsUG = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'payload' : formDataUG,
   'muteHttpExceptions':true
 };
 var optionsLG = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'payload' : formDataLG
 };
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('UrlFetchApp options ['+options+"]");
 //UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage?chat_id='+channelNumber+'&text='+text);
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage',optionsUG);
  Utilities.sleep(5 * 1000);
  result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage',optionsLG);
```

now I would like to make something like but, instead of sendMessage I would like to call a method of my bot
I use JavaScript Telegraf framework ATM, but I can change is not a problem.
I want to achieve something like:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/register',optionsUG);
```

here is the bot currently configured

```
const serverPath = "/home/bots/PlatoonAdvisor/telegram";

const commands = require(serverPath+'/package/modules/commands.js');
const config = require(serverPath+'/config.json');

var helpText = require(serverPath+'/package/help.txt');

const token = config.TELEGRAM_BOT_SECRET;

const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(token);
const REGISTER_COM = 'register';
const HELP_COM = 'help';
const REQUIREMENTS_COM = 'requirements';
const CAHT_ID_COM = 'chatid';


const getCommandParameters = function (text, command) {
  var reg = "/\/"+command+" (.*)/g";
  var arr = text.match(reg);
  return arr;
}

/*
bot.on('text', message=> {
  return message.reply('I am Grooth');
})
*/
bot.command(HELP_COM, ctx=> {
  return ctx.reply(helpText);
});
bot.command(REGISTER_COM, ctx=> {
  var replyMsg;
  var param = getCommandParameters(ctx.message.text, REGISTER_COM);
  var player_name, allycode;
  if (param != null) {
    try {
      var params = param.split(",");
      if (params.length < 2) {
        replyMsg = "Missing parameters, try /help if you need help :)";
        throw replyMsg;
      }
      player_name = params[1];
      allycode = params[0];
      var channel = ctx.chat.id;
      commands.registerTPlayer(player_name, allycode, channel);
      replyMsg = "Successfully registered player ${player_name} with allycode ${allycode}!"
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log (ex);
    }
  }
  return ctx.reply(replyMsg);
});
bot.command(REQUIREMENTS_COM, ctx=> {
  var param = getCommandParameters(ctx.message.text, REQUIREMENTS_COM);
  var params = param.split(",");
  var json = ctx.chat.id;
  return ctx.reply(json);
});
bot.command(CAHT_ID_COM, ctx=> {
  var id = ctx.chat.id;
  var msg = "The chat id requested is ${id}";
  return ctx.reply(msg);
});
bot.startPolling();
```

is that even possible? I'm looking over the internet for a while now and was not able to find any clue about.

EDIT: Doing some more digging I found webhooks to send content to a web server when something happens in the bot but not vice versa. I'm getting frustrated.

My goal is to update the local database with information the spreadsheet have but the bot still don't so users can later ask to the bot to retrieve those information.

I mean I could make an ajax call if it were a real web server, but it is just a spreadsheet which doesn't act as a server.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why are you sending a message to the bot using the spreadsheet script? So the bot can update a local database? For what are the users using the bot?

Comment: The reason was simple. The bot is an informative one that provide informations to the users throw commands and data manipulations. the need to send messages from outside was
1) to notify the users that new data was ready (solved)
2) feed the local database with new info (workarounded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I forgot to answer this question with the solution I found.

there is no way indeed to call a specific function of the bot from the outside because it is not a real function, it is a parsed string that a user type and the bot interpret as a command.

So I had to be creative and expose a RestServer from the bot itself (the NodeJS express library did the trick) which I was then able to call from the script.

[Here an handy guide for Express.js](https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api)

This is my solution which is working great now.